# How to validate a date in Python and have it so it is on or before a certain date?

Tags: python

I imported time from the time module and `datetime.now()` to try and make a function. The thing is, my format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, but `datetime.now()` returns this:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 7, 21, 24, 9, 308361).
```

and

```
time.strptime('2012-03-14','%Y-%m-%d')
```

returns this:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=74, tm_isdst=-1)
```

How do I make a function that gives me a valid date?

Answer (score 3):

Use `strftime` instead.

```
In [55]: datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[55]: '2013-02-08'
```

or

```
In [57]: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[57]: '2013-02-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print today.strftime('The date is %d, %h %Y')
```

Output

`The date is 08, Feb 2013`

Answer (score 0):

According to what your title asks for you can always do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

some_time_in_seconds = datetime.now().replace(year=<some_year> day=<some day>).strftime("%s")

now = time.time()

if int(some_time_in_seconds) - now > 0:
    #Some date is after now
```